# Можно добавить Объект в базу данных через Swagger UI, или нужен клиентский часть для добавления

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swaggerui

Есть мини проект для работы со складами и продуктами. В Solution'е добавил библиотеку классов и туда добавил контекст и репозиторий, подключил к базе данных ms sql server в контексте и создал миграцию. Во  втором проекте, проект типа WEB API. Там создал модели Product, Category, Storage. У меня вопрос, могу ли я через swagger UI добавлять объект типа Product, например, или мне нужен отдельный проект для клиента. Я попробовал через swagger, но у меня выходит ошибки.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private IRepository<Product> prodRepo;
    public ProductController()
    {
        prodRepo = new ProductRepository();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProductAsync() => await Task.Run(() => prodRepo.GetAll());

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(int id) => await Task.Run(() => prodRepo.Get(id));

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateProduct")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProductAsync([FromQuery] Product product)
    {
        if (product != null && product < 0)
            return await Task.Run(() => BadRequest());
        else
        {
            prodRepo.Create(product);
            return await Task.Run(() => BadRequest());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы все правильно сделали в API, то через Swagger,  в запросе типа POST, вы можете добавить новую запись в БД, без создания приложения - клиента. Собственно Swagger, в том числе и сделан для тестирования API, и генерации запросов.  Вполне возможно что при формировании запроса через Swagger, вы некорректно передаете данные...   Вот в этом [плейлисте](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9tfuEucw9-mValqMeOE3n4) пример создания API на .NET,  в том числе и такие сущности как Product

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak Понятно, в код для POST запроса есть ошибка ,где я выше показал

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но как-то странно у Вас получается... Если product не равен null и меньше 0, то Вы отвечаете BadRequest - у Вас Product можно сравнивать с числом?! А далее в else блоке Вы создаёте продукт, но он в этом блоке может быть null.